# java.lang.IllegalStateException(Method not found): Calling MockMvc.perform multiple time in one test with customized Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-test

For retrieving `UserDetails` object in spring security protected REST api with `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation, I add a customized filter in the `MockMvc` object, something likes:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class BaseSpringIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var context: WebApplicationContext

    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    val mockUser = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(MyUserDetails("MOCK_USER"), "MOCK_PASSWORD",  listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("MOCKED_ROLE")))

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(springSecurity(mockSpringSecurityFilter))
            .build()
    }

    private val mockSpringSecurityFilter = object: Filter {
        override fun doFilter(req: ServletRequest, res: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
            with ((req as HttpServletRequest).userPrincipal) {
                if (this != null)
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = this as Authentication
                }
            chain.doFilter(req, res)
        }

        override fun destroy() {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I try to call the `mockMvc` object twice in the some test as follows:

```kotlin
class DummyTests: BaseSpringIntegrationTest() {
    @Test
    fun dummyTest() {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("<MY_URL>").principal(mockUser))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().`is`(HttpStatus.OK.value()))

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("<ANOTHER_URL>").principal(mockUser))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().`is`(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
    }
}
```

When running the test, the `java.IllegalStateException` is thrown for the second `perform` likes:

```
Method not found: BaseSpringIntegrationTest$mockSpringSecurityFilter$1.getFilters(org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not found: BaseSpringIntegrationTest$mockSpringSecurityFilter$1.getFilters(org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(ReflectionUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionTestUtils.java:502)
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionTestUtils.java:427)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.support.WebTestUtils.findFilter(WebTestUtils.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.support.WebTestUtils.getSecurityContextRepository(WebTestUtils.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors$SecurityContextRequestPostProcessorSupport.save(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java:725)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors$TestSecurityContextHolderPostProcessor.postProcessRequest(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java:805)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:831)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:173)
```

And if there is only one `perform` call in a test, everything works properly.

Could anybody help to handle the problem please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding the following method to my MockSpringSecurityFilter

```
public void getFilters(MockHttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest){}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It really works! May I consider there is a defect somewhere?